# Can I connect an ADC directly to a DAC?

Tags: adc, dsp, dac

I'm planning to do some audio DSP soon but I would like to know if I can connect an ADC directly to a DAC without a processor in the chain. My main reason is to test preamp circuitry.  I would like the ADC and DAC to be 24-bit at 48 kHz, and I have many options ADC and DAC-wise.  I would also like to use I<sup>2</sup>S for communication so when I add a DSP, it will work seamlessly.

Is it as simple as connecting the clock and data lines?

Comment: mention the exact partnumbers or parts u r going to use...then it is easy to answer....

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the parts you're using.  ADCs and DACs are more likely than not going to be slaves that would expect some controller to give them a clock signal.

If you want to test a preamp, could you just use a signal generator in place of the DAC output?  That, or design in whatever DSP you want to use and write some quick code that simply passes values through.